# Resign iOS app without specifying identity

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin-studio, codesign

I am currently developing an app in Xamarin Studio, where I would like to modify the build info.plist via a script. Xamarin Studio unfortunately lacks a script build phase however, so my only option is really to run a script after the build, which of course breaks the signing.

Since different identities are used for different configurations I cannot make the identity static, and either way I'd really like to interfere with Xamarin as little as possible (I.E. be able to use the project settings etc).

Is there a way to resign the app using the identity it is currently signed with, via a shell script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import subprocess
import re
import os

app_path = os.path.abspath(sys.argv[1])

signing_info = subprocess.Popen(['codesign', '--display', '--verbose=4', app_path], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, close_fds=True).communicate()[0]

identity = re.search('Authority=(.*)', signing_info).group(1)

subprocess.call(['codesign', '--sign', identity, '--force', '--preserve-metadata=entitlements,resource-rules,requirements', '/Users/stefanfisk/Projekt/Tunaspot/Xamarin/App/Touch/bin/iPhone/Ad-Hoc/Touch.app'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to modify `Info.plist` and after that resign your application bundle again. I have never tried to do so, but I believe, it should work.

Comment: yes, but how do I resign the bundle using the same identity that it was previously signed with?

Comment: Don't you know which one was previously used? You should have all provision profiles and signing identities on your machine.

Comment: I can find out by reading the build log, but I don't know how to script it.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried `xcodebuild` command, Identity is specified in the build configuration so you just need to mention the configuration.. you can find xcodeproj in /obj/xcode/somewhere

```
xcodebuild -project Xamarin.xcodeproj  -scheme TestApp -configuration "Ad Hoc"
```

Comment: I have this all working properly in several Xcode projects, but that's only because the script build phase makes it trivial to implement.

Comment: how would that work? there is not xcodeproj, only Visual Studio solution and project files.

Comment: in there I can only find the temporary Xcode projects used when editing xibs. during build nothing xcode related is created in the obj folder, and when looking at the build output I cannot see xcodebuild being called anywhere, only mtouch.